# Change background-color CSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Hi I have a jQGrid which creaty cells like this:

```
       <td role="gridcell" 
       title=" Hull City AFOdds: 1.74Stake: 27Ret: 46.98Ben: 0.98(Back)" 
       aria-describedby="list2_bet_2">...</td>
```

I would like to give this td a custom style with jQuery. How could I access to its CSS??

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem really about targetting th correct TD or about using jQuery's `css()` function?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the value of the `aria-describedby` atttribute in advance you can target the `td` with:

```
jQuery("td[aria-describedby='list2_bet_2']")
```

So then to modify the background-color

```
jQuery("td[aria-describedby='list2_bet_2']").css('background-color','#f00');
```

Answer (score 0):

To set all TD elements of the table:

```
$('td').css('background-color', 'red');
```

If you want to set only a specific TD, use another selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test each row and that cell contents you can do something like the following which iterates over each row and colors the cell red if both of the tested cells for that row are 0:

```
var rowIds = $(grid).jqGrid('getDataIDs');

for (i = 1; i <= rowIds.length; i++) {
    rowData = $(grid).jqGrid('getRowData', i);

    //check on TradeAmount and FoilTradeAmount Cells
    //color background red if both are 0...the user should have to selecte a postive value of either cell
    if (rowData['TradeAmount'] == 0 && rowData['FoilTradeAmount'] == 0) {
        $(grid).jqGrid('setCell', i, 'TradeAmount', "", { 'background-color': '#F08080', 'background-image': 'none', 'font-weight': 'bold' })
        .jqGrid('setCell', i, 'FoilTradeAmount', "", { 'background-color': '#F08080', 'background-image': 'none', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
    } //if
    else {
        $(grid).jqGrid('setCell', i, 'TradeAmount', "", { 'background-color': '#5ccd06', 'background-image': 'none', 'font-weight': 'bold' })
        .jqGrid('setCell', i, 'FoilTradeAmount', "", { 'background-color': '#5ccd06', 'background-image': 'none', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
    }
} //for
```

If you just want to style ever cell in a column you could do something like

```
.className td[aria-describedby="GridName_RowName"] {background-color: #F08080;}
```

and then part of your grid initialization you test each row and add a class if some condition is met:

```
        rowattr: function (rd) {//if the row is displaying an inactive user, give it a different CSS style
            if (rd.CellName!= 0) { return { "class": "DeckListMissingAmount" }; } //if

        },
```